# Is there any way to trigger solar eclipses faster?

Tags: terraria

I just had a solar eclipse followed by a blood moon, but it’s been almost 46 nights since I beat the first mech boss, and the eclipse happened right after beating Plantera a second time.

Is there some kind of probability that defeating certain bosses triggers a solar eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

Solar Eclipses have a 5% chance of occurring each day (starting after defeating one of the mechanical bosses), but they can also be forced by assembling a [Solar Tablet](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Solar_Tablet).

Since you've beaten Plantera, you should have access to the Jungle Temple, which has both chests (which can hold a Tablet), and mobs farmable for Solar Tablet fragments (you'll need 8).